# Retrive post by tags PHP code

Tags: functions

For example, i am building a cinema site..

For movies - I am using post - The movies are post there.. For actors - I am using post_type : persoane , Taxonomy : lista.

How can i retrive the movies play by bruce willis in
http://cinema.trancelevel.com/persoane/bruce-willis/

For example, i have : http://cinema.trancelevel.com/the-cold-light-of-day-2012-2/ This movie have Bruce Willis Tag....( this is a regolar post in wp)

In Bruce Willis page i want to retrive the movie.... that have Bruce Willis Tag

In conclusion i want to display the movies that actor play in

I anny body know please help. Thanks in advance

I try this but no sucess

```
<?php $args = array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => get_query_var('term')

    )
  )
);
query_posts( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  echo get_post_format();
endwhile; else:
  echo 'No movie found';
endif;
wp_reset_query();      
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are multiple issues here:

1) Because you're using `query_posts()` the post object's query_vars are inherited by your new `query_posts()`. I suspect then, that `'post_type' => 'persoane'` is implicitly part of that query posts call. If you switch to using WP_Query instead of query posts, I suspect that will fix the issue.

2) Have you double checked that `get_query_var('term')` is returning what you expect? I think that only works on taxonomy archive pages. Instead, you'll want do use `get_the_tags()`.

Comment: can you give me the exacte code please, will be apreciated... Thanks

Comment: If I have time later, I'll try to work something up, but I couldn't even give you exact code without knowing more about what you want (e.g. how do you handle a post with multiple tags?). Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags and http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. They both have **multiple** code snippets that should take you quite far. If you can't get it working, post a follow up question and ping me here in the comments.

Comment: i do not know php so much, can you please paste the code... i'm tring to get the movie http://cinema.trancelevel.com/the-cold-light-of-day-2012-2/ , to link to the actor http://cinema.trancelevel.com/persoane/bruce-willis/ by tag.... so wen i add a movie in POSTS, i add a tag name Bruce Willis, after i go to PERSOANE ( new post_Type) i add the person... and under i need the code for displaying the movies play by actor by tag. i can give you acces with team wiew if you want...

Comment: more: http://cinema.trancelevel.com/1.jpg , im using custom field, in post i get actors by Relationship for each movie... ok ... but how can i display automatic post (movies) that actor play in.... Note: i use for : =>>Movies : POSTS for Actors ==> post_type PERSOANE , Taxonomy lista...